# Get Start Stop data in difference Array

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I have two tables: 1st is Location table and 2nd is Stoppage table.

```
Location Table fields
======================
UserID    Gpsdatetime       Latitude    Longitude
-------------------------------------------------
1   2020-02-12 01:03:18.000 23.421976   72.083997
1   2020-02-12 02:46:09.000 23.033492   72.558313
1   2020-02-12 03:45:43.000 23.033473   72.598341
1   2020-02-12 04:59:19.000 23.035310   72.565583
1   2020-02-12 05:59:09.000 23.043310   72.558583
1   2020-02-12 06:58:59.000 23.053310   72.578583
1   2020-02-12 07:58:49.000 23.033510   72.588583

Stoppage table fields
======================
UserID  StartTime                EndTime                IsStoppage
1       2020-02-12 01:03:18   2020-02-12 02:46:09         1
1       2020-02-12 03:45:43   2020-02-12 03:47:43         0
1       2020-02-12 03:47:43   2020-02-12 03:59:43         0
1       2020-02-12 03:59:43   2020-02-12 04:30:43         0
1       2020-02-12 04:30:43   2020-02-12 04:59:19         0
1       2020-02-12 04:59:19   2020-02-12 05:59:09         1
1       2020-02-12 05:59:09   2020-02-12 06:58:59         1
1       2020-02-12 06:58:59   2020-02-12 07:58:49         1
```

Now I want record like if `IsStoppage=1` then get Latitude and Longitude point based on stoppage record end time.

Next, if `IsStoppage=0` then record should be like Latitude and Longitude points between StartTime of first record of isstoppage 0 to last record endtime of Is stoppage 0.

Next, again next record IsStoppage is 1 then get Latitude and Longitude point of IsStoppage record.

I need an array like this:

```
"trackdata": [
  {
    "UserID": 1,
    "StartTime": "2020-02-15T01:27:57",
    "EndTime": "2020-02-17T02:24:26",
    "IsStoppage": true,
    "TrackArray": [
      "Latitude": 23.033463,
      "Longitude": 72.558346
    ]
  },
  {
    "UserID": 1,
    "StartTime": "2020-02-15T03:27:57",
    "EndTime": "2020-02-17T04:24:26",
    "IsStoppage": false,
    "TrackArray": [
      {
        "Latitude": 23.033463,
        "Longitude": 72.558346
      },
      {
        "Latitude": 23.033463,
        "Longitude": 72.558346
      },
      {
        "Latitude": 23.033463,
        "Longitude": 72.558346
      },
      {
        "Latitude": 23.033463,
        "Longitude": 72.558346
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "UserID": 1,
    "StartTime": "2020-02-15T05:27:57",
    "EndTime": "2020-02-17T06:24:26",
    "IsStoppage": true,
    "TrackArray": [
      "Latitude": 23.033463,
      "Longitude": 72.558346
    ]
  }
]
```

so is it possible to get records in like my requirement in SQL server query OR any logic in C# code.

Comment: Seems your `Json` data is not valid. Post the correct `Json`

Comment: so, what have you tried so far?